# Why rmdir remove folder after program exit?(Using Dev C++ in Win7)

Tags: c, windows, rmdir

I'm trying to write a function which named myremoved. I want it to remove a non-empty folder.
But now I have a problem, when I using the function(code below) to remove all files and folder, "rmdir" says folder is removed, but when I open Windows Explorer I saw folders which have beed reported removed still exist there(I try to access,but it denied.).

This is function "myremove" code:

```
int myremove(char *dirname){
    /*
      myremove(Folder name):Remove all files and folders in that. 
    */
    DIR  *folder;  
    struct _finddata_t c_file; 
    char str[256]; 
    long hasfile; 
    int a,result=0;

    _chdir(dirname); 
    hasfile =_findfirst("*",&c_file);
    if(hasfile!=-1){
        do{
            str[0]='\0';
            strcat(str,c_file.name);
            if((strcmp(str,".")!=0)&&(strcmp(str,"..")!=0)) {
                //Is it a folder or not 
                if ((folder = opendir(c_file.name)) == NULL)    {         
                    //Not a folder,using remove to delete it
                    if((a=remove(c_file.name))==0){
                        printf("Remove: %s OK.\n",c_file.name);
                }else{
                        result=-1;
                        printf("Remove: %s Failed.\n",c_file.name);
                    }       
                }else{
                    closedir(folder);
                    if((a=myremove(c_file.name))!=0){result=-1;}
                }
            }
        }while( _findnext( hasfile, &c_file )==0 );
    }
    _chdir("..");
    if ((folder = opendir(dirname)) != NULL){
        if((a=rmdir(dirname))!=0){
            result=-1;
        printf("Remove: %s Failed.\n",c_file.name);
        }else{
            printf("Remove: %s OK.\n",c_file.name);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char dirname[256],ch;
    printf("Please enter the folder name which you want to remove:");
    gets(dirname);
    if (strlen(dirname)!=0){
        printf("Notice:It will remove %s folder and all things in this folder，sure to continue[Y/N]?",dirname);
        scanf("%c",&ch);
        if(ch=='Y'){
            if (myremove(dirname)==0){
                printf("Folder %s Removed.\n",dirname);
            }else{
                if (rmdir(dirname)==0){
                    printf("Folder %s Removed.\n",dirname);
                }else{
                    printf("Folder %s couldn't be removed.\n",dirname);
                }

            }
        }else if (ch=='N'){
            printf("User cancel, program will exit.\n");    
        }
}else{
        printf("Nothing input,program will exit.\n");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not really answering your question, but is the second `opendir` call really needed? I think it's unnecessary. In addition, if you remove it, it might solve your problem.

Comment: I just try it,but it still failed.

Comment: You seem to have a resource leak in your branch `if ((folder = opendir(c_file.name)) == NULL) `. In the true branch, you never close the directory opened with opendir. Also, that if statement is not a good way to see if a file is a directory or not. `opendir` will fail for many reasons, failing because the filename you give it is actually a directory is just one possibility

Comment: So, I need to add a statement into true branch to avoid it really is a folder?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved this problem by myself.
Because I use `_findfirst` and `_findnext`, but forgot to use `_findclose`.
So the folder been locked until the program end.
Thanks help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>


int myremove(char *dirname){
    DIR  *folder; 
    struct _finddata_t c_file; 
    char str[256];
    long hasfile; 
    int a,result=0;

    _chdir(dirname);
    hasfile =_findfirst("*",&c_file);
    if(hasfile!=-1){
        do{
            str[0]='\0';
            strcat(str,c_file.name);
            if((strcmp(str,".")!=0)&&(strcmp(str,"..")!=0)) { 
                if ((folder = opendir(c_file.name)) == NULL)    {         
                    if((a=remove(c_file.name))==0){
                        printf("Remove: %s OK.\n",c_file.name);
                    }else{
                        result=-1;
                        printf("Remove: %s Failed.\n",c_file.name);
                    }       
                }else{
                    closedir(folder);
                    if((a=myremove(c_file.name))!=0){result=-1;}
                }
            }
        }while( _findnext( hasfile, &c_file )==0 );
        _findclose(hasfile);
    } 
    _chdir("..");
    if((a=rmdir(dirname))!=0){
        result=-1;
        printf("Remove: %s Failed.\n",dirname);
    }else{
        printf("Remove: %s OK.\n",dirname);
    }
    return result;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char dirname[256],cmmd[20],ch;
    printf("Please enter folder name which you want to remove:");
    gets(dirname);
    if (strlen(dirname)!=0){
        printf("Notice:Now start to %s delete action, sure to continue[Y/N]?",dirname);
        scanf("%c",&ch);
        if(ch=='Y'){
            if (myremove(dirname)==0){
                printf("Folder %s Removed.\n",dirname);
            }else{
                printf("Folder %s Remove failed.\n",dirname);           
            }
        }else if (ch=='N'){
            printf("User cancel, program will exit...\n");  
        }
    }else{
        printf("Input empty, program will exit...\n");
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```